# Spring, Gradle compiling error with org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure

Tags: java, spring

I want to write my own IM using Spring Framework.
I read this one:

[Getting Started - Messaging with RabbitMQ](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/)

When I compile this code below I get this error message:
http://pastebin.com/7gNJBAE2

I will be grateful for any help or advise.

I'm using:
Windows 8.1,
Java 8,
NetBeans 8.0.2.,
Gradle 2.5

Receiver.java

```
package hello;

    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

    public class Receiver {

        private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        public void receiveMessage(String message) {
            System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
            latch.countDown();
        }

        public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
            return latch;
        }

    }
```

Application.java

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    final static String queueName = "spring-boot";

    @Autowired
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("spring-boot-exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    Receiver receiver() {
        return new Receiver();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Waiting five seconds...");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Sending message...");
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, "Hello from RabbitMQ!");
        receiver().getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        context.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration#transactionManager due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)

It seems that your source file is in `src/main/java` instead of being in `src/main/java/demo`

Didn't you add the `package hello;` manually? I copy pasted that code in a fresh project created from start.spring.io and it worked without touching anything.

Comment: Stéphane Nicoll
Can You send mi this project by for example by sendspace?
I've done the same thing like You, but without any kind of good results.\

Comment: I used start.spring.io and I created demo project with hello packet but I have no idea how to add it in NetBeans.

Comment: I took the code you pasted in your own description and it works for me. I am afraid I can't help you much more.